# Folder disappearing from /var/run upon reboot with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, socket

I'm running `php5-fpm` on Ubuntu using a `UNIX` socket at `/var/run/php5-fpm/www.conf.sock`. During the installation I have created manually the `php5-fpm` folder inside `/var/run/` so that `php5-fpm` could create its socket in it, which it can. The problem is that whenever I restart my computer the `php5-fpm` folder disappears from `/var/run` and `php5-fpm` is no longer able to create the socket, thus every time I reboot I need to create the `/var/run/php5-fpm/` folder again manually. I could put that routine in the `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` startup script but am wondering the following:

**Are there any reasons why the `/var/run/php5-fpm/` folder should be removed upon reboot?**

info: I'm running `ubuntu 12.04` desktop (I'm planning on using the server version on a hosting but am for now doing some testing with the desktop version on my laptop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `df -T`, you will find a line similar to this:

```
none         tmpfs     1028284      3888   1024396   1% /var/run
```

This means that `/var/run` is a [temporary file storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs). So, it is not maintained between reboots.

You need to create the folder each time you start your service/daemon if not already created.