# Subdirectory of /var/run disappearing in CentOS 7 while running

Tags: centos7, rhel7, var

Occasionally (after some amount uptime which I haven't measured yet), my `/var/run/projectname` directory will disappear along with the `/var/run/projectname/gunicorn.sock` file.

Rebooting brings it *back* as I *do* have it configured in `tmpfiles.d`:

```
d /var/run/projectname 0775 207 root -
```

The `supervisord` services recreate the `.sock` file at reboot, which is a Django gunicorn socket that nginx uses to deploy the app.

`/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` doesn't include `/var/run` and I don't have a `tmpwatch` job in `/etc/cron.daily` either.  `/var/spool/cron` is empty and `/etc/cron.*` doesn't have a relevant job either.

Any ideas of what could be wiping this ...or how to audit it?

Note: This is not a duplicate of [Folder disappearing from /var/run upon reboot with Ubuntu 12.04](https://serverfault.com/questions/400947/folder-disappearing-from-var-run-upon-reboot-with-ubuntu-12-04) because that question complains about the files disappearing *after* a reboot.  My problem is when the system is still running.

Comment: Why are you using supervisord?

Comment: It's the standard for how we deploy apps via our ansible scripts.